# How to convert string to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, iteration

I want to convert this string to array of objects.

Here is my String

```
var a = 'SG 925|AMD-MAA|19:15|21:40|SG 703|VNS-BOM|19:45|22:05';
```

I want to convert like this

```
[
{'name':'SG 925','place':'AMD-MAA','from':'19:15','to':'21:40'}
{'name':'SG 703','place':'VNS-BOM','from':'19:45','to':'22:05'}
]
```

Here is what i have tried so far

```js
var a = 'SG 925|AMD-MAA|19:15|21:40|SG 703|VNS-BOM|19:45|22:05';
a = a.split("SG ");
a = a.filter(function(e){return e}); 
console.log(a);
```

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znohcwa3/12/)

How can i do this in javascript?

Comment: Do names always start with `SG`?

Comment: Yes it always starts with SG, so i thought of doing string split to make it array..

Comment: Problem with that is you remove the `SG` when you split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined exaclty what the keys are gonna be like you could use something like this.

```js
var a = 'SG 925|AMD-MAA|19:15|21:40|SG 703|VNS-BOM|19:45|22:05'
const arr = a.split('|')
const objArr = []

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=4) {
 objArr.push({
   name: arr[i],
        place: arr[i+1],
        from: arr[i+2],
        to: arr[i+3]
  })
}

console.log(objArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 'SG 925|AMD-MAA|19:15|21:40|SG 703|VNS-BOM|19:45|22:05';
a = a.split("|");
answer = [];
a.forEach(function(value, i) {
  if(i % 4 == 0) {
     answer.push({
       name: a[i],
       place: a[i + 1],
       from: a[i + 2],
       to: a[i + 3]
     })
  };
})
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. :)

```js
function convert(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('|');
  var objArr = [];
  for(var i=0; i<strArr.length; i=i+4){
   objArr.push({
    'name':strArr[i],
    'place':strArr[i+1],
    'from':strArr[i+2],
    'to':strArr[i+3]
   })
  }
  return objArr;
}

console.log(convert('SG 925|AMD-MAA|19:15|21:40|SG 703|VNS-BOM|19:45|22:05'));
```